# TeX Editor for Arabic language?

Tags: editors, arabic, right-to-left

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)
>   [Typesetting a document using Arabic script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/typesetting-a-document-using-arabic-script)

I'm Arab and use TeX Live 2012. I have a problem with TeXworks: It doesn't support right-to-left (rtl) texts well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: check this out http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43519/15717 may be it works for you

Comment: Instead of more answers asking about specific features of editors, we should add more details to the entries of our big question. Some of them already include information on "RTL/bidi", have a look at that.

Comment: Texmaker is a good editor with miktex